# Getting the fields of MS Project

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

I am developing a MS Project addin in C#, and would like to get all the visible name in the active project programatically.

[image]

I recorded a VBA macro, to see how it gets the column name ; but the macro only has SelectTaskColumn .

```
 User action :-  selected the "Duration" field

 VBA Code :- SelectTaskColumn Column:="Duration"
```

How do I get all the visible field names.